# Rails FactoryGirl association conflicts with unique validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a `presentation` which belongs to a `participant` which in turn belongs to `user`.

My FactoryGirl class definitions are:

```
  factory :presentation do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Some topic nr #{n}" }
    association :participant
  end

  factory :participant do
    name "John Doe"
    association :user, :guest
  end

  factory :user do
    trait :admin do
      ident 1000
      roles ["admin"]
    end

    trait :guest do
      ident 9000
      roles ["guest"]
    end    
  end
```

When I run my `spec`: `FactoryGirl.create_list(:presentation, 3)` I get the error that the user is already taken as the `ident` value needs to be unique.

The thing is, I don't want to create new objects for every presentation. It should belong to the same `participant` object (and hence the same `user` object).

So what I want: to create 3 presentations belonging to the *same* participant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of association you can use after build:

```
  factory :presentation do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Some topic nr #{n}" }

    after(:build) do |s|
        unless Participant.count == 0
          s.participant = Participant.first
        end
        s.participant ||= create(:participant)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `participant` first,

```
@participant = FactoryGirl.create(:participant)
```

And, then assign that `participant` while creating presentations,

```
@presentations = FactoryGirl.create_list(:presentation, 3, participant: @participant)
```